# How can i calculate that normal lays in same part of plane with point?

Tags: 2d, geometry, trigonometry

I.e. n0 for A and n1 for B. Plane divided by plane CD.

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the center:

```
p0 = (C + D) * 0.5
```

Now, take the relative vector from the center to the point in question:

```
p1 = (X - p0)
```

Finally, take the dot product with the normals you might want:

```
d0 = n0.dot(p1)
d1 = n1.dot(p1)
...
etc.
```

Then, check to see if its greater than zero

```
abovePlane0 = d0 > 0
abovePlane1 = d1 > 0
```

... 
   etc.

Comment: Is
`p0 = (C + D) * 0.5`
the same, as just coordinates of vector CD
`D-C`

Comment: No. `(C + D) * 0.5` is the midpoint between C and D.

Comment: And `X` - my point of interest ?

Comment: X, meaning A, B, etc. the point you want to check.

Comment: I believe finding midpoint is superfluous. Knowing just two vectors (n and CA) dot product can be found and its sign checked for being smaller or greater than zero.

Comment: Greater then zero means normal lays in the same plane with A ?

Comment: The normal divides the world into 2 regions: those with a positive dot product and those with a negative dot product. A is in the positive dot product with n1. B is in the negative dot product with n1, but the positive dot product with n2.